# euclidean distance in siamese network

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, siamese-network

I came across a code for siamese network in which the euclidean distance was calculated as:

```
def euclidean_distance(vects):
  x, y = vects
  sum_square = K.sum(K.square(x - y), axis=1, keepdims=True)
  return K.sqrt(K.maximum(sum_square, K.epsilon()))
```

In this code why are we taking maximum of the sum_square and epsilon?

Answer (score -1):

"Epsilon is small value (1e-07 in TensorFlow Core v2.2.0) that makes very little difference to the value of the denominator, but ensures that it isn't equal to exactly zero."

in a simple explanation, is just to ensure that the result value can be used in next calculations with no error.

Comment: Why the quotes? If you are quoting from some source, please include an explicit reference.